# Running multiple apache spark streaming jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, streaming, amazon-emr

I'm new to Spark streaming and as I can see there are different ways of doing the same thing which makes me a bit confused.

This is the scenario:
We have multiple events (over 50 different events) happening every minute and I want to do some data transformation and then change the format from json to parquet and store the data in a s3 bucket. I'm creating a pipeline where we get the data and store it in a s3 bucket and then the transformation happens (Spark jobs). My questions are:

1- Is it good if I run a lambda function which sorts out **each event type** in a **separate subdirectories** and then read the folder in sparkStreaming? or is it better to **store all the events in a same directory** and then read it in my spark streaming?

2- How can I **run multiple sparkStreamings at the same time?** (I tried to loop through a list of schemas and folders but apparently it doesn't work)

3- Do I need an orchestration tool (airflow) for my purpose? I need to look for new events all the time with no pause in between.

I'm going to use, **KinesisFirehose** -> **s3** (data lake) -> **EMR**(Spark) -> **s3** (data warehouse)

Thank you so much before hand!

Comment: it is always good to decouple multiple flow and making code modular ... i would prefer  each event type in a separate subdirectories and then read the folder in sparkStreaming ... in this way i have much more control on different eventType and one evenType does not impact other flow if you correctly modularise code ...

Comment: How can I run multiple sparkStreamings at the same time? create and executor threadpool and iterator on file types and create separate streamingContext inside each thread which handle a particular type of event  data.